# Token Comma Expected- JSON power query

Tags: json, api, powerquery

I am unable to run the query because it says there is a token comma expected and highlights the "donordrive" in "donordrive-password".

let
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.donordrive.com/cmndancemarathon/export/commit.JSON", [Headers=[#"donordrive-email" ="email@gmail.com”, #"donordrive-password" ="password2020"])),
result = Source[result],

#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(result, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),

#"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"donationentereddate", "eventfiscalyear", "donationamount", "donationisregistrationfee", "participantid", "participantfirstname", "participantlastname", "teamname", "donorfirstname", "donorlastname"}, {"Column1.donationentereddate", "Column1.eventfiscalyear", "Column1.donationamount", "Column1.donationisregistrationfee", "Column1.participantid", "Column1.participantfirstname", "Column1.participantlastname", "Column1.teamname", "Column1.donorfirstname", "Column1.donorlastname"})

in
#"Expanded Column1"

Comment: please use the Code Sample feature, when including code in your question

Comment: I suggest looking through https://kohera.be/blog/power-bi/the-hidden-gems-of-the-function-web-contents/